# How to avoid robot detection?

Tags: python, web-scraping, mechanize, robots.txt

I'm using python+mechanize, attempting to scrape a site. If I visit this site with links, a text-only version of the login page appears. This is what I'd like to see with my scraper. So:

```
import mechanize

USER_AGENT = "Links (2.3pre1; Linux 2.6.32-5-xen-amd64 x86_64; 80x24)"
mech = mechanize.Browser(factory=mechanize.RobustFactory())
mech.addheaders = [('User-agent', USER_AGENT)]
mech.set_handle_robots(False)

resp = mech.open(URLS['start'])
fnout("001-login.html", resp.read())
resp.close()
```

`fnout` just dumps the string to a file. Yet, when I open `001-login.html`, the entirety of the page is the word "Robot". Nothing else.

I haven't made any other requests. It's not like I loaded the page & didn't load the images, or whatever. This was the first request I made, and I put the User-Agent as exactly what the version of Links that the site worked with had. What am I doing wrong (besides trying to scrape a site that doesn't want to be scrape, that is)?

Comment: Do you really think that web servers or applications have a dedicated text-only version for people browsing from the console?

Comment: I think that is pretty dependent on the site. Have you tried with other user agents such as those of popular browsers?

Comment: As an aside, you might want to look into [the ``with`` statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) - and [``contextlib.closing``](http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing) if ``Browser.open()`` doesn't support a context manager natively.

Comment: Another possibility is that the page in question has some JavaScript on it that's there to detect robots. Does the site's robots.txt file have something like `User-agent: * \n Disallow: /` ?

Comment: @C2H5OH: I do not. I figured it would be easier to figure out the problem if I showed that the site *does* deliver content to Links, but not to my screen scraper. My python program has a lot more in common with links than with Chrome. Case in point, I thought "Jim Mischel"'s question would be implicitly answered, given that links does not process javascript.

Comment: @JimMischel: it actually doesn't seem to have a `robots.txt` file. That would just be in `/robots.txt` yes? That file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably there are other headers that `links` is sending that Mechanize is not, or vice versa. Hit up http://www.reliply.org/tools/requestheaders.php with both `links` and Mechanize and see what headers are being sent.

Comment: I would vote you up if I had 15 reputation. Soon, soon, perhaps.

Comment: Hmm... I've made the headers match exactly with links - `Accept-Language`, `User-Agent`, `Accept-Encoding`, and `Connection` - yet still, the site just replies with "Robot". What could it possibly be? That's the very first thing the site returns to me. What does it have access to besides the request headers, that it could be using to figure out it's from Python and not from Links? (I also tried with Chrome's User-Agent, and the result was the same.)

Comment: Are you sure your output file is getting updated on your latest runs? i.e. are you looking at old results?

Comment: @RussellBorogove: thanks for asking. that has happened before and driven me quite insane :P. in this case, i've been alternating between the `reliply` site and the site I'm scraping, so the same output file has been constantly changing from a full-blown HTML page to a sad, barren wasteland with but five characters, to wit: R - o - b - o - t.

Comment: hmm I am daft. i've been opening a different page on Links (/) than on my mechanize attempts (/ProcessLogin.aspx). the outputs now match (links says 'Robot' if i open /ProcessLogin.aspx directly). that at least clears up that confusion.. now to see if it will say 'Robot' when I post the appropriate form data